# Xcode: Clean and Build in a single step

Tags: xcode

In Xcode, you can do a Clean from the Product menu.

You can also do a Build (also from the Product menu).

However, can you combine both? i.e. is it possible to do a Clean then Build in a single step?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is no exist! At most Shift-Command-K and Command-B unfortunately for us:(