# Xcode: why can you not Clean then Build in one step?

Tags: ios, xcode

I was wondering here: [Xcode: Clean and Build in a single step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907352/xcode-clean-and-build-in-a-single-step)

how to `Clean` then `Build` your Xcode project in one single step.

I've still found no answer so perhaps there's a logical reason why you have to `Clean` then wait for that step to finish before doing a `Build`. It might only take a second or two but when you're repeating these steps over and over it seems bizarre they haven't been combined.

Any logical answers?

Comment: you can add custom script to clean it. also i guess you didn't work on project that takes minutes to build?

Answer (score 1):

The clean and build operation are sequential. If you don't clean, old cached files will be used (saves time , if they are unchanged). IF you "clean", all files will be recompiled/re-processed/re-generated - costing a bit in time, but yielding a fresh start -  sometimes the programs(Xcode) try to be too smart and get mixed up - too many old files left from previous builds. The clean sometimes solves that problem.